# How do I use Chosen jQuery in my html file?

Tags: jquery, html

How do I apply Chosen jQuery in my html page?

I have a `select` form so I need to use the `multiple select` by Chosen to make it look more user friendly.

```
<select class="chosen" multiple="true" name="faculty">
        <option value="AC">A</option>
        <option value="AD">B</option>
        <option value="AM">C</option>
        <option value="AP">D</option>
</select>
```

I've downloaded the files and copied it into my webpage folder.

So, what I did was include the `chosen.jquery.min.js` in `<head>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And the instruction says to Call the chosen plugin: `$(".chzn-select").chosen();`

I don't know where to put that JavaScript statement in order to invoke Chosen multiple select. I thought it was as easy as using Bootstrap, hah. Any help?

Comment: if you've included the file into your page, it should just be as simple as creating <script> at the bottom of the page and including your javascript code in there

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you follow one of [Bootstrap's example markup structures](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/getting-started.html#examples), you'll notice that they call all their JavaScript files at the bottom (right above the `</body>` tag).

You'll want to do the same; something like:

```
    </div> <!-- /container -->

    <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="../assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/script.js"></script>     <!-- Your custom JS -->

  </body>
</html>
```

Inside this `script.js` file, you'll want to add something like:

```
$(function(){
    $(".chzn-select").chosen();
});
```

Comment: What does .chosen() even do. I cant find any documentation on the method.

Comment: @pnizzle "Chosen is a jQuery plugin that makes long, unwieldy select boxes much more user-friendly." https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ `.chosen()` is how you apply the plugin to a selector.

Comment: Right right. I've had a closer look at it. Very useful.

Answer (score 22):

Your `select` must have the class `chzn-select`, and normally you would run a script after page load like the following:

```
$(function() {
    $(".chzn-select").chosen();
});
```

Below is a tested, working example:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.css">
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(".chzn-select").chosen();
});
</script>

<select class="chzn-select" multiple="true" name="faculty" style="width:200px;">
        <option value="AC">A</option>
        <option value="AD">B</option>
        <option value="AM">C</option>
        <option value="AP">D</option>
</select>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $(".chzn-select").chosen();
});
</script>

<select class="chzn-select" multiple="true" name="faculty">
        <option value="AC">A</option>
        <option value="AD">B</option>
        <option value="AM">C</option>
        <option value="AP">D</option>
</select>
```