# How to position the select element while using Chosen?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-chosen

I'm using inputs from this question:
[How do I use Chosen jQuery in my html file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13939369/how-do-i-use-chosen-jquery-in-my-html-file)
So I have a select box, but the problem is I'm having trouble styling the select element.I used left and top % in CSS to position it, but it does not work.How can I position and style the select element?

http://jsfiddle.net/NWD9Q/3/

A little snippet:

```
<select class="chzn-select" multiple="true" name="faculty" style="width:200px;">
    <option value="AC">A</option>
    <option value="AD">B</option>
    <option value="AM">C</option>
    <option value="AP">D</option>
</select>
```

Comment: wrap it in a div and style the div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chzn-container` will be the right class to add position and this can done in 2 ways.

1. Adding the attribute directly in **chosen.css** file.
2. Adding the attribute via jQuery as mentioned below.

`$(".chzn-container").css({"left":"20%"});`

**DEMO** in [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/NWD9Q/4/).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to add css to the `select`, add to the wrapping `ul` , `.chzn-choices`

```
     .chzn-choices{

left:25%;    
    }
```