# how to search in combobox by database

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox, dataset, database-connectivity

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dr = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from cus_mas_det", conn);
    ds = new DataSet();

    dr.Fill(ds, "cus_mas_det");
    DataTable CodeDesc = new DataTable();
    conn.Open();
    dr = new MySqlDataAdapter("select tvl_code, concat_ws(',', tvl_code, citi_name) citiname from code_desc where travel_mode = 'BUS'", conn);
    ds1 = new DataSet();
    dr.Fill(ds1);
    ddlfrom.DataSource = ds1;
    ddlfrom.DataTextField = "citiname";
    ddlfrom.DataValueField = "tvl_code";
    ddlfrom.DataBind();
    txtbookingdate.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
    txtbookingdate.ReadOnly = true;
    txtbookingref.Text = autoid();
    txtbookingref.ReadOnly = true;
}
```

I have a asp page in which I have textboxes and comboboxes, I am populating the combobox from the database, as given in the above code, and I am able to populate that.
Now my problem is I want to search the elemnets by typing any words in the combobox..
For example, if I type word "Ab" it should show all the elements starting with "Ab"..
How to do that?

```
   <asp:ComboBox ID="ddlfrom" class="chzn-select" runat="server"  
                                            DataTextField="name" DataValueField="name" MaxLength="0" 
                                            style="display: inline;" 
                                            onselectedindexchanged="ddlfrom_SelectedIndexChanged1">

                                        </asp:ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use chosen jquery plugin from here [harvesthq.github.io/chosen/](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

So you can search keyword within drop-down list try this plugin.

This may help you to use [How do I use Chosen jQuery in my html file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13939369/how-do-i-use-chosen-jquery-in-my-html-file)

Add required js and css files to page assign class to dropdown like this:-

```
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/chosen/chosen.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $(".chzn-select").chosen();
});
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
```

Assign class to your dropdown

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dr_list" runat="server" CssClass="chzn-select">
   <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text=""></asp:ListItem>
      </asp:DropDownList>
```

Download [Here](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/releases)

Comment: exactly that is what i need..can u please tell me how and where should i add that plugin..??

Comment: you dont need to change chosen.js file.just update question with modified code.Did you assign class to your dropdown?

Comment: i am doing same thing...still not coming..:(

Comment: no any error is showing...i am just getting all the values from database in my dropdownlist like i was getting previously...no change...

Comment: try using dropdown list see if it's working instead of combobox

Comment: can u tell me that where i have to add your part1 code (i.e link rel=....)....exactly..may be i am going wrong in that...

Comment: Within your page <head></head> section this js and css file can be linked

Comment: in the asp page in which i have that particular combobox..?

Comment: yes,why are u using combobox which version asp.net u are using?

Comment: 4.0...well i am working on a functionality something very similar to makemytrip...so i needed one combobox in which i can type the words to search the elements or else i can see the elements by dropdownlist...and i have to populate the combobox from database which i have done...now i just need that search functionality...

Comment: use this $(".chzn-select").chosen({allow_single_deselect: true}); instead of
$(".chzn-select").chosen();

Comment: i have edited that part.. well in the asp page i dont have that <head></haed> syntax....so where should i add the whole code.?..in the master page or in asp page only..?..and if in asp page..then where exactly..?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this client side using AJAX.

1. Create a web service or use a page method which takes as a parameter some search text and then returns the data you need.
2. Client side - handle the keypress event using JavaScript/jQuery and update your combo box or whatever control you are using at that point.

Example using jQuery:

```
$('#<%= txtBox.ClientID %>').keypress(function () {

    var currentText = $(this).val();

    $.get('some_web_service', { searchText: currentText }, function (data) {
        // update combo box here using data
    });

});
```

This assumes you have a web service called some_web_service which will return the data you need.

Alternatively you could put the whole thing in an UpdatePanel and handle the keypress event but the performance of this will not be as good.

Comment: u mean i have to add a new jscript file for tht..??

Comment: In a seperate javascript file or you could put the javascript within <script type="text/javascript"></script> tags in the page

Comment: why do i need web service for that..?..can u please explain..?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to have a list of values update when a user starts typing in a textbox. This is an event that needs to be handled client side, so you use JavaScript to do so. However, the list of values you have needs to change, and they need to come from the server. The only way to do this is to use your script to go back to the server to get the values, so you need a Web Service or PageMethod for the script to go to.

Comment: okk i have done it so far...now what all i have to do in the page method..??

Comment: Read this: http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do such seraching with ASP.Net combo boxes rather you should try some thing  [like](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)